# Why must I include the received files in my source control with ApprovalTest?

Tags: java, approval-tests

I was reading the documentation of `ApprovalTest - Getting Started.pdf` ([it's in the zip here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/approvaltests/files/ApprovalTests.Java/)) and the last thing it says under **Approving The Result** is "Note: you must include the received files in your source control."

This really confused me.  Can someone explain why this is?  Is this a typo that meant to say: "Note: you must include the **approved** files in your source control."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you must include **only approved** files in your source control. Received files should be automaticaly deleted after execution, if there are no any differences with approved. If there are any differences, approvals tests do not pass.

Comment: OK thanks a lot.  I don't feel like creating a bunch of individual questions for this, but maybe I should: Is approval-tests on a public maven repository?  I couldn't find it from a search.

Comment: I have no idea because of using ApprovalTests with other languages

Comment: I'm not seeing it in Maven Central

Comment: I couldn't find it in a public repo either and this site confirmed that. https://github.com/mzagar/approvals-example

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for bringing this documentation error to our attention, we fixed the document.   This is a typo - it should read 'approved files'.

Comment: In the Approval Library zip file, it still says "received files" in the getting started PDF.  This is in version 013.